# Rename tag [gameplay3d] to [gameplay3d-engine]

Tags: discussion, tags

I have created the tag [gameplay3d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameplay3d) yesterday, but I realized shortly after that I should have named it [gameplay3d-engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameplay3d-engine) to reflect a bit more what it is and improve users who search stuff based on the "engine" keyword.

Is there a way to re-name it?

Comment: I can merge it sometime today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've renamed the tag as requested.